# Double da -nan(0xFFFFFFFF)

Tags: c++, redes-neuronales

Tengo un codigo de una red neuronal, y cuando le paso las pruebas de vez en cuando me da `New recent average error: -nan`. Me imagino que sera algo de un número de tipo "double" fuera de rango o algo asi, cuando me meto en el debugger y veo el valor de la variable double sale `0xfffffffffff`. El codigo es :

```
    // neural-net-tutorial.cpp
    // David Miller, http://millermattson.com/dave
    // See the associated video for instructions: http://vimeo.com/19569529


    #include <vector>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <cassert>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <sstream>

    using namespace std;

    // Silly class to read training data from a text file -- Replace This.
    // Replace class TrainingData with whatever you need to get input data into the
    // program, e.g., connect to a database, or take a stream of data from stdin, or
    // from a file specified by a command line argument, etc.

    class TrainingData
    {
    public:
        TrainingData(const string filename);
        bool isEof(void) { return m_trainingDataFile.eof(); }
        void getTopology(vector<unsigned> &topology);

        // Returns the number of input values read from the file:
        unsigned getNextInputs(vector<double> &inputVals);
        unsigned getTargetOutputs(vector<double> &targetOutputVals);

    private:
        ifstream m_trainingDataFile;
    };

    void TrainingData::getTopology(vector<unsigned> &topology)
    {
        string line;
        string label;

        getline(m_trainingDataFile, line);
        stringstream ss(line);
        ss >> label;
        if (this->isEof() || label.compare("topology:") != 0) {
            abort();
        }

        while (!ss.eof()) {
            unsigned n;
            ss >> n;
            topology.push_back(n);
        }

        return;
    }

    TrainingData::TrainingData(const string filename)
    {
        m_trainingDataFile.open(filename.c_str());
    }

    unsigned TrainingData::getNextInputs(vector<double> &inputVals)
    {
        inputVals.clear();

        string line;
        getline(m_trainingDataFile, line);
        stringstream ss(line);

        string label;
        ss>> label;
        if (label.compare("in:") == 0) {
            double oneValue;
            while (ss >> oneValue) {
                inputVals.push_back(oneValue);
            }
        }

        return inputVals.size();
    }

    unsigned TrainingData::getTargetOutputs(vector<double> &targetOutputVals)
    {
        targetOutputVals.clear();

        string line;
        getline(m_trainingDataFile, line);
        stringstream ss(line);

        string label;
        ss>> label;
        if (label.compare("out:") == 0) {
            double oneValue;
            while (ss >> oneValue) {
                targetOutputVals.push_back(oneValue);
            }
        }

        return targetOutputVals.size();
    }


    struct Connection
    {
        double weight;
        double deltaWeight;
    };


    class Neuron;

    typedef vector<Neuron> Layer;

    // ****************** class Neuron ******************
    class Neuron
    {
    public:
        Neuron(unsigned numOutputs, unsigned myIndex);
        void setOutputVal(double val) { m_outputVal = val; }
        double getOutputVal(void) const { return m_outputVal; }
        void feedForward(const Layer &prevLayer);
        void calcOutputGradients(double targetVal);
        void calcHiddenGradients(const Layer &nextLayer);
        void updateInputWeights(Layer &prevLayer);

    private:
        static double eta;   // [0.0..1.0] overall net training rate
        static double alpha; // [0.0..n] multiplier of last weight change (momentum)
        static double transferFunction(double x);
        static double transferFunctionDerivative(double x);
        static double randomWeight(void) { return rand() / double(RAND_MAX); }
        double sumDOW(const Layer &nextLayer) const;
        double m_outputVal;
        vector<Connection> m_outputWeights;
        unsigned m_myIndex;
        double m_gradient;
    };

    double Neuron::eta = 0.15;    // overall net learning rate, [0.0..1.0]
    double Neuron::alpha = 0.5;   // momentum, multiplier of last deltaWeight, [0.0..1.0]


    void Neuron::updateInputWeights(Layer &prevLayer)
    {
        // The weights to be updated are in the Connection container
        // in the neurons in the preceding layer

        for (unsigned n = 0; n < prevLayer.size(); ++n) {
            Neuron &neuron = prevLayer[n];
            double oldDeltaWeight = neuron.m_outputWeights[m_myIndex].deltaWeight;

            double newDeltaWeight =
                    // Individual input, magnified by the gradient and train rate:
                    eta
                    * neuron.getOutputVal()
                    * m_gradient
                    // Also add momentum = a fraction of the previous delta weight;
                    + alpha
                    * oldDeltaWeight;

            neuron.m_outputWeights[m_myIndex].deltaWeight = newDeltaWeight;
            neuron.m_outputWeights[m_myIndex].weight += newDeltaWeight;
        }
    }

    double Neuron::sumDOW(const Layer &nextLayer) const
    {
        double sum = 0.0;

        // Sum our contributions of the errors at the nodes we feed.

        for (unsigned n = 0; n < nextLayer.size() - 1; ++n) {
            sum += m_outputWeights[n].weight * nextLayer[n].m_gradient;
        }

        return sum;
    }

    void Neuron::calcHiddenGradients(const Layer &nextLayer)
    {
        double dow = sumDOW(nextLayer);
        m_gradient = dow * Neuron::transferFunctionDerivative(m_outputVal);
    }

    void Neuron::calcOutputGradients(double targetVal)
    {
        double delta = targetVal - m_outputVal;
        m_gradient = delta * Neuron::transferFunctionDerivative(m_outputVal);
    }

    double Neuron::transferFunction(double x)
    {
        // tanh - output range [-1.0..1.0]

        return tanh(x);
    }

    double Neuron::transferFunctionDerivative(double x)
    {
        // tanh derivative
        return 1.0 - x * x;
    }

    void Neuron::feedForward(const Layer &prevLayer)
    {
        double sum = 0.0;

        // Sum the previous layer's outputs (which are our inputs)
        // Include the bias node from the previous layer.

        for (unsigned n = 0; n < prevLayer.size(); ++n) {
            sum += prevLayer[n].getOutputVal() *
                    prevLayer[n].m_outputWeights[m_myIndex].weight;
        }

        m_outputVal = Neuron::transferFunction(sum);
    }

    Neuron::Neuron(unsigned numOutputs, unsigned myIndex)
    {
        for (unsigned c = 0; c < numOutputs; ++c) {
            m_outputWeights.push_back(Connection());
            m_outputWeights.back().weight = randomWeight();
        }

        m_myIndex = myIndex;
    }


    // ****************** class Net ******************
    class Net
    {
    public:
        Net(const vector<unsigned> &topology);
        void feedForward(const vector<double> &inputVals);
        void backProp(const vector<double> &targetVals);
        void getResults(vector<double> &resultVals) const;
        double getRecentAverageError(void) const { return m_recentAverageError; }

    private:
        vector<Layer> m_layers; // m_layers[layerNum][neuronNum]
        double m_error;
        double m_recentAverageError;
        static double m_recentAverageSmoothingFactor;
    };


    double Net::m_recentAverageSmoothingFactor = 100.0; // Number of training samples to average over


    void Net::getResults(vector<double> &resultVals) const
    {
        resultVals.clear();

        for (unsigned n = 0; n < m_layers.back().size() - 1; ++n) {
            resultVals.push_back(m_layers.back()[n].getOutputVal());
        }
    }

    void Net::backProp(const vector<double> &targetVals)
    {
        // Calculate overall net error (RMS of output neuron errors)

        Layer &outputLayer = m_layers.back();
        m_error = 0.0;

        for (unsigned n = 0; n < outputLayer.size() - 1; ++n) {
            double delta = targetVals[n] - outputLayer[n].getOutputVal();
            m_error += delta * delta;
        }
        m_error /= outputLayer.size() - 1; // get average error squared
        m_error = sqrt(m_error); // RMS

        // Implement a recent average measurement

        m_recentAverageError =
                (m_recentAverageError * m_recentAverageSmoothingFactor + m_error)
                / (m_recentAverageSmoothingFactor + 1.0);

        // Calculate output layer gradients

        for (unsigned n = 0; n < outputLayer.size() - 1; ++n) {
            outputLayer[n].calcOutputGradients(targetVals[n]);
        }

        // Calculate hidden layer gradients

        for (unsigned layerNum = m_layers.size() - 2; layerNum > 0; --layerNum) {
            Layer &hiddenLayer = m_layers[layerNum];
            Layer &nextLayer = m_layers[layerNum + 1];

            for (unsigned n = 0; n < hiddenLayer.size(); ++n) {
                hiddenLayer[n].calcHiddenGradients(nextLayer);
            }
        }

        // For all layers from outputs to first hidden layer,
        // update connection weights

        for (unsigned layerNum = m_layers.size() - 1; layerNum > 0; --layerNum) {
            Layer &layer = m_layers[layerNum];
            Layer &prevLayer = m_layers[layerNum - 1];

            for (unsigned n = 0; n < layer.size() - 1; ++n) {
                layer[n].updateInputWeights(prevLayer);
            }
        }
    }

    void Net::feedForward(const vector<double> &inputVals)
    {
        assert(inputVals.size() == m_layers[0].size() - 1);

        // Assign (latch) the input values into the input neurons
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < inputVals.size(); ++i) {
            m_layers[0][i].setOutputVal(inputVals[i]);
        }

        // forward propagate
        for (unsigned layerNum = 1; layerNum < m_layers.size(); ++layerNum) {
            Layer &prevLayer = m_layers[layerNum - 1];
            for (unsigned n = 0; n < m_layers[layerNum].size() - 1; ++n) {
                m_layers[layerNum][n].feedForward(prevLayer);
            }
        }
    }

    Net::Net(const vector<unsigned> &topology)
    {
        unsigned numLayers = topology.size();
        for (unsigned layerNum = 0; layerNum < numLayers; ++layerNum) {
            m_layers.push_back(Layer());
            unsigned numOutputs = layerNum == topology.size() - 1 ? 0 : topology[layerNum + 1];

            // We have a new layer, now fill it with neurons, and
            // add a bias neuron in each layer.
            for (unsigned neuronNum = 0; neuronNum <= topology[layerNum]; ++neuronNum) {
                m_layers.back().push_back(Neuron(numOutputs, neuronNum));
                cout << "Made a Neuron!" << endl;
            }

            // Force the bias node's output to 1.0 (it was the last neuron pushed in this layer):
            m_layers.back().back().setOutputVal(1.0);
        }
    }


    void showVectorVals(string label, vector<double> &v)
    {
        cout << label << " ";
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
            cout << v[i] << " ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }


    int main()
    {
        TrainingData trainData("/tmp/trainingData.txt");

        // e.g., { 3, 2, 1 }
        vector<unsigned> topology;
        trainData.getTopology(topology);

        Net myNet(topology);

        vector<double> inputVals, targetVals, resultVals;
        int trainingPass = 0;

        while (!trainData.isEof()) {
            ++trainingPass;
            cout << endl << "Pass " << trainingPass;

            // Get new input data and feed it forward:
            if (trainData.getNextInputs(inputVals) != topology[0]) {
                break;
            }
            showVectorVals(": Inputs:", inputVals);
            myNet.feedForward(inputVals);

            // Collect the net's actual output results:
            myNet.getResults(resultVals);
            showVectorVals("Outputs:", resultVals);

            // Train the net what the outputs should have been:
            trainData.getTargetOutputs(targetVals);
            showVectorVals("Targets:", targetVals);
            assert(targetVals.size() == topology.back());

            myNet.backProp(targetVals);

            // Report how well the training is working, average over recent samples:
            cout << "Net recent average error: "
                    << myNet.getRecentAverageError() << endl;
        }

        cout << endl << "Done" << endl;
    }
```

El fichero al que hace referencia para recoger las muestras es el resultado del siguiente codigo :

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <cstdlib>

    using namespace std;
    int main(){


        cout <<"topology: 2 4 1"<<endl;
        for(int i =2000; i>=0;--i){

            int n1 =(int)(2.0*rand()/double(RAND_MAX));
            int n2 =(int)(2.0*rand()/double(RAND_MAX));
            int t = n1 ^ n2;
            cout <<"in: "<<n1 << ".0 "<<n2 <<".0 "<<endl;
            cout <<"out: "<<t<<".0"<<endl;

        }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Así que la mayor parte del tiempo funciona? Lo siento, pero con este montón de código será difícil entender por qué recibió este `recent average error`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"*NaN (Not a Number)*" No es un Número.

---

Algunas operaciones matemáticas con números en coma flotante dan como resultado *NaN* cuando se hace una operación matemática que no tiene representación en el tipo de dato almacenado. Los principales sospechosos suelen ser la división entre cero (que podría dar *Inf*) o la raíz cuadrada de un número negativo...

¡Oh, sorpresa! tienes raíces cuadradas en tu código:

```
m_error = sqrt(m_error); // RMS
```

Operar sobre un *NaN* propagará el error, pero posiblemente el origen esté en esta operación.

Yo depuraría el código poniendo un punto de interrupción condicional sobre `m_error` para cuando esta variable sea negativa.

Comment: vale, muchas gracias. Cambiare el codigo a ver que tal

Comment: Ya nos harás saber de tus progresos, tengo curiosidad :)

Comment: Ahora no entiendo que pasa, estoy compilando el mismo codigo en un ordenador de la universidad, y no sale ese mensaje de error. Me imagino que es por la vercion de g++..... Ahora todas las pruebas salen bien .... Por cierto, la version de g++ en la que estoy actualmente es 5.4.0, si tienes otra version intenta compilarlo a ver que te sale

Comment: Cuando hay comportamientos inconsistentes entre compiladores, es posible que estés entrando en el terreno del "*comportamiento indefinido*" o del "*comportamiento definido por la implementación*", echa un vistazo a [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/164188/2742) para saber más del tema.

Comment: ya lo silucione. lo que hice fue agregar la siguiente linea :          double Net::m_recentAverageError =0.0;     y cambiar a "static" dicho atributo dentro de la clase Net. No cambia el resultado y no da el -nan

Comment: Por lo que describes, el problema podría estar relacionado con una falta de inicialización de las variables. ¡Es buena práctica inicializarlas! Te animo a buscar/hacer preguntas sobre el tema.

Comment: Gracias, yo suelo hacerlo, pero como podras ver en las primeras lineas comentadas, el codigo no es mio. Lo uso mas que todo para entender el funcionamiento de las redes neuronales, y me encontre con este problema. Aun asi, muchas gracias por tu apoyo !!!